# Device farm in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs

Does Azure has the capability to setup a device farm like AWS Device Farm  to test Android, iOS, and web apps on a massive collection of real mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Azure does not provide testing services for mobile apps. There are [7 best device farms to test your iOS and Android applications](https://medium.com/binwell-blog/7-best-device-farms-to-test-your-ios-and-android-applications-7efb834dab25).

Answer (score 0):

You may use Visual Studio App Center Test (formerly Xamarin Test Cloud), it supports some frameworks and language, you may find yours within it  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/